# Add classList.add to nth-child of custom HTML5 tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, selectors-api

I have custom tag `<movie>`. I want to manipulate onclick (every one of them separately) by adding class or doing something different. This is my code.

```js
window.onload = function()
{
    var movie1 = document.getElementsByTagName("movie")[0];
    var movie2 = document.getElementsByTagName("movie")[1];
    var movie3 = document.getElementsByTagName("movie")[2];
    var movie4 = document.getElementsByTagName("movie")[3];
    movie1.onclick = function() {
        movie1.classList.add("transparent");
        }
    movie2.onclick = function() {
        movie2.classList.toggle("transparent");
        }
    movie3.onclick = function() {
        movie3.parentNode.removeChild(movie3);
        }
    movie4.onclick = function() {
        movie4.innerHTML = movie2.innerHTML;
        }
};
```

```html
<container>
  
   <movie>
      <title></title>
      <img src="" alt="" />
      <p></p>
    </movie>
  
     <movie>
      <title></title>
      <img src="" alt="" />
      <p></p>
    </movie>
  
     <movie>
      <title></title>
      <img src="" alt="" />
      <p></p>
    </movie>
  
     <movie>
      <title></title>
      <img src="" alt="" />
      <p></p>
    </movie>
  
  
  </container>
```

I am sure this is not the best way to do this, and I tried using the document.querySelectorAll to make the code shorter, but couldn't do it.
Is there a better and shorter way for this to be done? I can keep doing it like this, but it will be very educational if you show me a better way.

Comment: Indeed, introducing errors in the form of new tag names is not the best way to do this. Also, most browsers will not appreciate the reuse of the title element in this way.

Comment: Can you suggest a better way to do this with pure javascript?

Answer (score -1):

If you can use jQuery,
  `var movies = $('movie');
    movies.click(function(){
        if ($(this) == movies[0])
            {$(this).addClass('transparent');}
        if ($(this) == movies[1])
            {$(this).toogleClass('transparent');}
       if ($(this) == movies[2])
           {$(this).remove();}
       if ($(this) == movies[3]}
           {$(this).html(movies[1].html());}
});`

Comment: Thank you for the answer but im interested in doing this without any libraries like jquery. Can you please give me an alternative for this with pure javascript?

Comment: Instead of $('movie') use document.querySelectorAll('movie'), $(this) becomes this, instead of addClass() use the same thing you provided in the OP, and instead of html() use innerHTML = /jQuery is just a simplification of JS methods !